# Skipping video and audio with PS3MediaServer

Tags: server, networking, streaming, transcode, ps3

I'm using the latest PS3MediaServer build right from the repos suggested in the Ubuntu Wiki. I'm streaming multiple movies from my server (Ubuntu 10.04 LTS) to my PS3 over wireless.

Sometimes, during some movies, the audio and the video will begin skipping. This can last anywhere between 5 and 30 seconds before it goes back to normal. I have a four core i5 processor and 8GB of DDR3 RAM so I don't think my computer is having a hard time keeping up with the transcoding. So this leads me to believe it's either sub-optimal transcoding options from within PS3MS or my network can't handle the heat.

Other than the out-of-box configuration, is there any way I can tweak the settings for the application to use my resources more efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Transcoding High Definition video usually means sending it in a more compatible format which can often take more bandwidth that a typical  wifi network can handle

Have you tried using a cable between your computer and ps3 to compared the results?

Either way PS3 media server is no longer being actively maintained and the fork called [universal media server](https://www.universalmediaserver.com/) actually supports setting bandwidth limitations that can help smoothen your playback.